# While reading data from Excel Sheet got NullpointerException

Tags: java, vba, excel, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to read data from a excel sheet but getting NullPointerException every time when reading data at the cell index =6. Put while(value != null) to avoid null values but still got the exception without any output.
I am putting the screen shot of excel sheet from where i am trying to get data. [image]

```
Code-
package com.selenium;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Exxcel {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception,NullPointerException{
    //WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    //WebElement wb;
    try{
    FileInputStream file= new FileInputStream("C:\\Documents and Settings\\OMEGA\\Desktop\\Test Planning And Documents\\Automation Data.xlsx");
    Workbook data=WorkbookFactory.create(file);
    Sheet sheet=data.getSheet("Sheet1");
    for(int i=1;i<=sheet.getLastRowNum();i++){
        Row row= sheet.getRow(i);
        int j=0;
        String value=row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
        while(value != null){ 
        System.out.println(value);
        }//while
        while(value == null){
            j++; 
         }  
    }//for

         /*while(j1==9){
             String value=row.getCell(j1).getStringCellValue();
             System.out.println(value);
             }//while2
             */
    }catch(NullPointerException n){n.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Null");
        }// catch
    }//main
 }//class


StackTrace-
Null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.selenium.Exxcel.main(Exxcel.java:22)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not enough to check that `row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue() != null`. You should check that `row.getCell(j) != null`.

In addition, your while loops makes no sense :

The first one will either do nothing or print value forever (since you are not changing value inside the loop).

```
    while(value != null) { 
        System.out.println(value);
    }//while
```

The second one will either do nothing or increment j forever (since you are not changing value inside the loop).

```
    while(value == null) {
        j++; 
    }
```

I suggest you replace them with the following code :

```
Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
if (row != null) {
    for (int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
        if (row.getCell(j) != null) {
            if (row.getCell(j).getCellType() == CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                String value=row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
                if(value != null) { 
                    System.out.println(value);
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Did the code changes as said by you but still getting the exception without any value/output

Comment: @Shantanu In which row do you get the exception? Perhaps you should verify that row != null too.

Comment: for code line 1=(int j = 1; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
     code line 2=if (row.getCell(j) != null) {                  code line 3=String value=row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();. Here in line one i am getting exception. I think because i am trying to assign index=1 which is null in line 2 i am getting the exception. I am not able to figure out why the while loop is not working?

Comment: @Shantanu I added another condition to the answer. You have to check the type of the cell before calling getStringCellValue. Otherwise, you get an exception if it's not a String cell.

Comment: i wrote one more code by using same and almost similar steps and that code is running fine and gives exception only when it gets a null cell. So i think cell type is not a problem here. The only difference in both codes is in the other program the excel sheet is having data on the first row

Comment: @Shantanu In that case, simply add a check that row != null.

Comment: @EranSir it worked when i put row != null.... But i am getting the output in a single line. Is it possible to get value of each cell independently. For example String s1 = value of cell 1, String s2= value of second cell

Comment: @Shantanu You can store these values in an ArrayList<String> instead of storing them in the same String variable.

Comment: I used array like this--for (int j = 1; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
       if (row.getCell(j) != null) {
           String value=row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
           String[] array= new String[i];
           array[j]=value;
           if(array[j] != null) { 
               System.out.println(array[6] +"Also" + array[9]);
           }
       }  
   }

Comment: But the output which i am getting is But getting output like this Website Alsonull
nullAlsoAddress
timesjobsAlsonull
nullAlsohttp://www.timesjobs.com/
naukariAlsonull
nullAlsohttps://login.naukri.com/nLogin/Login.php?
monsterAlsonull
nullAlsohttps://my.monsterindia.com/login.html?src=http://my.monsterindia.com
shineAlsonull
nullAlsohttp://www.shine.com/myshine/login/

Comment: @Shantanu You gain nothing by creating the array inside the loop, since the values read in previous columns would be overriden. In addition, using an array is not recommended in your case, since you don't know in advance the number of Strings you would have to store in this array. Initializing the array to have i elements makes no sense, since i is just the index of the current row.

Comment: @EranHow to do that sir?

Comment: @Shantanu at the beginning (before you start reading the rows), do `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>()`; Then do `list.add(value)` each time you read a new value from the file.